# PI2 Reading data from RFID RC522 Mifare

Tags: python, rfid

so i am trying to get the data from a *mifare* card and i can't get the same reading i get on windows.
On windows my card data is a 10 digit code like: **4852658522**
Even though i can dump the data on the card i can't translate it to get the same 10 digit code.
Anyone has done this before?
Using python to read and dump the data.

Comment: What data do you get in RPi?

Comment: I can dump all the sectors on the Mifare card

Comment: no, you wrote that in windows you get 10 digit code, what code do you get in RPi? How are you reading the data in windows?

Comment: Ok, the cards are read-only. i got them like that. On windows i have a mifare reader that outputs that 10-digit, i don't really access the sectors of the card but on the pi i have to access the sector and somehow translate it and that's what i don't know how to do :/

Comment: @TiagoMartins The data on the card can be converted to a number in a million million million ways.  The PC code is using one conversion.  You need to know how it makes that conversion.  There is no point in guessing.

Comment: It can be UID of the card. The UID is 4 bytes, as I know. So, with the RPi read the sector 0 of the card and post it here.

Comment: Sector 0 [48, 63, 172, 124, 223, 136, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Windows reading: 2091663152

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Sector 0 [48, 63, 172, 124, 223, 136, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>   Windows reading: 2091663152

2091663152 represented in hexadecimal is 7C AC 3F 30.  If those bytes are shown in decimal they are 124 172 63 48.

It is too much of a coincidence to believe those happen by chance to be the first four numbers in sector 0.  I guess they are the UID as [Michael](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/46595/michael) suggested.

So read the first four numbers from sector 0, call them n1, n2, n3, n4.

The UID is then (n4<<24 | n3<<16 | n2<<8 | n1).

Comment: Well, i've reached a similar conclusion in the meanwhile. I've been able do do the conversion and can now get the same readings on windows and the pi. ty